# Redirect based on last numbers in url after the hyphen

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to do the following redirect using .htaccess:

http://www.example.com/blue/widgets/item-4_description-12345.htm to /index.php?id=12345

What would be the best regular expression to extract the digits after the last hyphen and a dot?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following:

```
RewriteRule ^.*-(\d+)\.htm$ /index.php?id=$1
```

Untested, but see if that helps. This is based on my knowledge of RegEx, and the [examples I found](http://forums.devshed.com/apache-development-15/htaccess-redirect-regex-489562.html) from [various places](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html).

There's also a [helpful site](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/) that automates the process of .htaccess modifications, though I don't see anything pertaining to RegEx.